# I'm on Ubuntu 20,I got this error while reloading synaptic,tried to solve NO_PUBKEY thing several times,but couldn't,do help

Tags: apt, synaptic

`Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/root/.synaptic/tmp//tmp_sh' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C99B11DEB97541F0The repository 'https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease' is not signed.`

Synaptic > Reload > got this pop up error

Comment: Please provide OS & release details (*there is no Ubuntu 20 release; do you mean Ubuntu Core 20 as it's a different product to the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system*) and `synaptic` is a *deb* package manager so won't run on 20 systems (it'll run on *year.month* releases like 20.04 which are *deb* based systems, 20 or *year* format is for *snap* only products).

Comment: yes,it's Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Please correct your question - answers on this site are for your question (comments where we ask you about the question, comments get deleted and answers are to be on your actual).  An answer will currently be for your stated Ubuntu 20 which I take it as meaning Ubuntu Core 20 or a *snap* only product of Ubuntu which cannot use `synaptic` (`synpatic` handles *deb* packages and 20 cannot use *deb* packages)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)